# why is my strcmp ending my program abruptly?

Tags: c, string, strcmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void processString(char *str, int *totVowels, int *totDigits);

int main()
{
    char str[50], *p;
    int totVowels, totDigits;

    printf("Enter the string: \n");
    fgets(str, 80, stdin);

    if (p = strchr(str, '\n')) *p = '\0';

    processString(str, &totVowels, &totDigits);
    printf("Total vowels = %d\n", totVowels);
    printf("Total digits = %d\n", totDigits);

    return 0;
}

void processString(char *str, int *totVowels, int *totDigits)
{
    int i, j;
    char tester[11] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};

    *totDigits = 0;
    *totVowels = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(str[i]))
        {
            *totDigits += 1;
        }
        else if(isalpha(str[i]))
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 11; j++)
            {
                if (strcmp(str[i], tester[j]) == 0)
                {
                    *totVowels+=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code is trying to calculate the number of times a number and vowel appeared in a string.

My string compare is trying to check for vowels but the program ends when it reaches the `strcmp` line. Why is that happening? Is my syntax wrong?

P.S. I'm only allowed to edit in the `processString` function, the rest are all given.

Comment: If you don't get a compilation error for `strcmp(str[i],tester[j])` then fix your compiler settings until you do get an error.  It is a complete waste of time trying to run a program that has errors

Comment: To be a bit more explicit, `str[i]` and `tester[j]` are both a single `char`. Whereas `strcmp` requires them to be both `char *` (ie C strings). The compiler should be giving you warnings about that which you should not be ignoring. To check a single character do `if (str[i] == tester[j])`

Comment: [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/12149471)

Comment: `str` can hold 50 characters and you tell `fgets` to read up to 80 characters into it?

Comment: @NateEldredge it is given by the site, i can't edit that.

Comment: Ugh.  Whatever "the site" is, you might want to stop using it.

Comment: @NateEldredge And please let the rest of us know what site it is so we can avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems lies is the code `if (strcmp(str[i], tester[j]) == 0)`. Because you are referencing single-dimensional arrays, the dereference comes out to be a single character. Essentially you are comparing two `chars`, and `chars` can be compared for equality like `ints`. And `strcmp` is designed for comparing *strings*, not single `chars`. That is why it segfaults (segfaults are due to invalid pointer dereferences. In this case it tried to dereference a non-pointer. A definite no-no.)
The fix would be to replace that line with: `if (str[i] == tester[j])`.